# Error while installing ruby on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: apt, software-installation, ruby, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to install Jekyll by following [Jekyll on Windows Subsystem for Linux tutorial](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/windows/).
There is a steep to install ruby from [BrightBox](https://www.brightbox.com/docs/ruby/ubuntu/) repository. I had triggered following command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:brightbox/ruby-ng
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4 ruby2.4-dev build-essential dh-autoreconf
```

Last command produced following error:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4 ruby2.4-dev build-essential dh-autoreconf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ruby2.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ruby2.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby2.4'
E: Unable to locate package ruby2.4-dev
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'ruby2.4-dev'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'ruby2.4-dev'
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had installed Ubuntu 18.04 and there was not no package `ruby2.4 ruby2.4-dev` for Ubuntu 18.04 at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&section=all&arch=any&keywords=ruby2.&searchon=names) so, I have updated my command to as follows to install `ruby2.5 ruby2.5-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.5 ruby2.5-dev build-essential dh-autoreconf
```